# Bs4 tag not being found

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to make a web scraper for the target website. I am using the code below which works fine to find product info, but finding the price returns none. I don't understand why the price can't be found but every other tag can be. Thanks for any help in advance!

URL: https://www.target.com/p/rold-gold-fat-free-tiny-twists-pretzels-16oz/-/A-13325504#lnk=sametab

```
for data in soup.findAll('span',{'data-test':'product-price'}):
    global price
    price = str(data.text)
    print(price)
```

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that its loading after it captures like if you print your soup u won't find the price in it due to it being loaded by javascript i am very new to this so don't take my word for it but i think the solution is in using selenium or scrapy &scrapy-playwright
i might do a scraper for it if i am free and no one else helps you with this.

edit
i've tried doing a simple [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) scraper for that page seems to be working fine i probably should have choosed wait_for_selector instead of timeout but don't understand the right form to do it yet for playwright so just did timeout and got the resluts working fine
name,price
Rold Gold Fat Free Tiny Twists Pretzels - 16oz,$3.19

'''

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine


class TargetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'target'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.target.com/p/rold-gold-fat-free-tiny-twists-pretzels-16oz/-/A-13325504',
            meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                playwright_page_coroutines=[
                    PageCoroutine('wait_for_timeout', 3000)]
            ),
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_c)

        pass

    async def parse_c(self, response):
        yield {

            'name' : response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/span//text()").get(),
            'price' : response.css('span.web-migration-tof__PriceFontSize-sc-14z8sos-16.iyRiQZ::text').get()
        }
'''
```

done a selenium as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.target.com/p/rold-gold-fat-free-tiny-twists-pretzels-16oz/-/A-13325504"
driver.get(url)
try:

    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test='product-price']"))
    )

    name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/span")
    price = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@data-test='product-price']")
    for n in name:
        print(n.text)
    for i in price:
        print(i.text)
    time.sleep(5)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

hope this helps bud ..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thats interesting it probably is being loaded by javascript. Is there anyway to load the javascript with scrapy or would I have to use selenium?

Comment: added a scrapy-playwirght scraper for it bud incase u were interested